# Excel formula help needed - subtraction

Tags: excel, excel-formula

basically I have an excel table which will get updated every week. what I want to do is identify the differences which are more than 10% between the current week and the previous week. for ex in the table below, first column, 71-49 = 22. so i want that to stand out. every week there will be another row added behind "Grand Total" row.

```
 Week3  Week4   Grand Total
    71%      49%         68%
    68%      64%         64%
    90%      91%         91%
    61%      59%         60%
    74%      74%         74%
             26%         49%
```

I have an excel table that looks something like this. what I want to do is create another row after "Grand Total", in that row I want an If-statement which will basically say:

**If (one row behind Grand Total) - (two rows behind grand total) >= 10, write "big drop", else keep the cell blank**

can someone tell me a formula which i can use to do something like this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use INDEX and COLUMN():

```
=IF(INDEX(2:2,COLUMN()-3)-INDEX(2:2,COLUMN()-2)>0.1,"big drop","")
```

This will always look 3 columns over and subtract that from the value 2 columns over from where the formula is placed.

Note: This could be done with OFFSET() but that is a volatile function and should be avoided if possible.

[image]